# Geo search using Algolia in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, algolia

I'm using Algolia to get results in order to display them on a map.
However I am getting an empty array of results from this query:

```
private val mAlgoliaClient = Client(BuildConfig.ALGOLIA_CLIENT_ID, BuildConfig.ALGOLIA_SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY)

// Initialize the query for Algolia search
val query = Query()
   .apply {
       aroundLatLng = AbstractQuery.LatLng(9.94727, -84.50626)
       aroundRadius = 50000
       setQuery("")
    }
    mAlgoliaClient.getIndex("places").searchAsync(query) {
}
```

The `mAlgoliaClient` is properly initialized. The object inside Algolia is the following:

```
{
  "_geoloc": {
    "lat": 9.94727,
    "lng": -84.50626
  }
  "objectID": "uwddfadfddfaDDafm2dfad"
}
```